# Binding data to Syncfusion SfChart

Tags: c#, xamarin, statistics, syncfusion

I try to use Syncfusion graph in file Dashboard.xaml

```
<chart:SfChart x:Name="chart"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           Margin="10">

<chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
    <chart:CategoryAxis LabelRotationAngle="-45">
        <chart:CategoryAxis.Title>
            <chart:ChartAxisTitle Text="Date" />
        </chart:CategoryAxis.Title>
    </chart:CategoryAxis>
</chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

<chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
    <chart:NumericalAxis>
        <chart:NumericalAxis.Title>
            <chart:ChartAxisTitle Text="Intensity" />
        </chart:NumericalAxis.Title>
    </chart:NumericalAxis>
</chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

<chart:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding SymptomDates}"
                    XBindingPath="Date"
                    YBindingPath="Intensity" />
</chart:SfChart>
```

SymptomDates is array in Dashboard.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Dashboard : ContentPage
{
    public StatisticsClasses.SymptomDatesModel SymptomDatesModel;
    public ObservableCollection<StatisticsClasses.SymptomDatesDP> SymptomDates { get; set; }
        private int _symptomId = 2;
        public Dashboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
            SymptomDatesModel = new StatisticsClasses.SymptomDatesModel();
            SymptomDates = new ObservableCollection<StatisticsClasses.SymptomDatesDP>();
            SymptomDates.Add(new StatisticsClasses.SymptomDatesDP(DateTime.Now, "Headache", 2));
        }
}
```

DataPopint is from anothr file (StatisticsClasses.cs):

```
public class StatisticsClasses
{
    public class SymptomDatesDP
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Severity { get; set; }

        public SymptomDatesDP(DateTime Date, string Name, int Severity)
        {
            this.Date = Date;
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Severity = Severity;
        }
    }
    public class SymptomDatesModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<SymptomDatesDP> SymptomDatesInfoAll { get; set; }
        public SymptomDatesModel()
        {
            SymptomDatesInfoAll = new ObservableCollection<SymptomDatesDP>();
        }
    }
}
```

SymptomDates shoud have one record, but when I load my Xamarin C# app it just shows this empty graph:

[image: Empty graph]

How do I bind data properly to see in graph?

Comment: Try setting the BindingContext **after** you instantiate SymptomDates

Comment: Thanks, It helped,. But also I did stupid mistake - my field was called not Intensity, but Severity....